# ANDROID JAVA - Define all id's at once. (+create easy buttons)

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to programming in Java, i've managed to create a little calculator as a little test app.
But i think i am using way to much code for my needs.
So i've given a Button a name: buttonname
Now to change it's text when clicked i need to:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Button buttonname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        buttomname = (Buttom) findViewById(R.id.buttomname);

    }

    public void buttonnameOnClick(View v) {
        button1.setText ("NewText")
    }

}
```

(i've bolted everything i had to add)
So i had to do everything above + connect the buttonClick through the xml file.

So i was wondering if there is a easier way to define all objects so i dont have to do: **Button buttonname;** and **buttomname = (Buttom) findViewById(R.id.buttomname);** all the time.

And i was wondering if there is a easier way to auto create button events.

(I am used to Visual Studio, but now i am kinda lost in Android Studio. So on Visual Studio i just had to double click the button and type: buttonname.Text = "NewText";)

Comment: Android/Java code is always going to be pretty verbose, that's just the nature of the programming language. The particular problem of repeated `findViewById(int)` lookups can be mitigated by using [Butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to do approximately that

However, I'm not sure if you really need it.

Oh, and you don't have to find the same Button every time. You find it once in `onCreate` and store in a field.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have typo in

`buttomname = (Buttom) findViewById(R.id.buttomname);`

It should be

```
buttomname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttomname);
```

and you forgot ; in one line "didn't your IDE show error to you!!" and also small correction in

```
public void buttonnameOnClick(View v) {
    button1.setText ("NewText")
}
```

it should be

```
buttomname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            buttomname.setText ("NewText");
         }
     });
```

inside protected void onCreate.

2nd method:
And if you have define android:onclick="buttonnameOnClick" in XML then

```
public void buttonnameOnClick(View v) {
    button1.setText ("NewText")
}
```

To be corrected to

```
public void buttonnameOnClick(View v) {
    buttomname.setText ("NewText");
}
```

Comment: I just made the code up (so i do have a working one in Android Studio), my bad! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is partly correct,
however the

```
(Buttom) is wrong change it to (Button)
```

the other thing

```
public void buttonnameOnClick(View v) {
    button1.setText ("NewText")
}
```

can just be changed to:

```
 public void buttonnameOnClick(View v) {
    Button buttonTemp = (Button)v;
    buttonTemp.setText ("NewText");
}
```

Assuming you are calling the method from layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a loop if you have a lot of identical buttons to process

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        for (int btn_id : new int[]{
                R.id.buttomname
                , R.id.buttomname2
                , R.id.buttomname3
        }) {
            View v = view.findViewById(btn_id);
            if (v != null) {
                v.setOnClickListener(onClickButton);
            }
        }

  }


  // 
  private View.OnClickListener onClickButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          // .. handle click 
          if (view.getId()==R.id.buttomname2){
          }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you must use the onClickListener() method for Button object. 
Your code like this structure;

```
buttonname = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonname);

    buttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                 }
});
```

I recommend to your visit [Button | Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) page for Button.

Comment: But to change the text i still have to: Button buttonname; and buttomname = (Buttom) findViewById(R.id.buttomname);?

Comment: (the link you sent says i have to add code inside of the onCreate event, isnt is weird to create an event inside of another one?)